# XPath compare one statement with multiple statements

Tags: xpath, statements

I have this xpath:

```
//a[ substring-after( substring-before( @href , '.deviantart.com' ) , 'http://' ) != 'about' and substring-after( substring-before( @href , '.deviantart.com' ) , 'http://' ) != 'browse' and substring-after( substring-before( @href , '.deviantart.com' ) , 'http://' ) != 'chat' ]
```

and I want to be able to do something like this:

```
//a[ substring-after( substring-before( @href , '.deviantart.com' ) , 'http://' ) != [ 'about' , 'browse' , 'chat' ] ]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In xpath2 you can go

```
//a[not( substring-after( substring-before( @href , '.deviantart.com' ) , 'http://' ) 
     = ('about' , 'browse' , 'chat' )) ]
```

in pure xpath1 you are rather more limited, although if you are using xslt or some other context where you can define xpath variables you could probably make it a bit neater.

Comment: i'm using it in document.evaluate function in javascript and it doesn't works